# writing UI for web scraping

Tags: javascript, html, css, screen-scraping

I am trying to build a website for web scraping. It aims to scrape websites which are "shopping-like" (like amazon). 
I want the user to type an url and the scraped-website to open in a frame in my website (like an "iframe") so that the user could choose from it the features to scrape, very similar to "SelectorGadget" ([1](https://selectorgadget.com/)) or google's developer tools UI.
The problem is that "iframe" only opens the website, I want to change it (maybe change the "hover" (css design) and the listeners for every tag) and also be able to get the css selectors out of it. Is there any efficient way to make it work?

I am quite new to web programming, I know HTML, javascript, css, and I am very willing to learn any other tool that could help. 
I would use any advice or relevant sources.

Comment: You're going to have legal issues if you try to modify someone else's website...

Answer (score 0):

You've got to rethink how your solution might look like.

You can't access another site's tags due to COORS limitations, but you can definitely scrape a site like Amazon. My recommendation is to use scrapy, as it's very simple to configure, and you can build a basic spider in under 50 lines of code in most cases.

Here's a YT video explaining [how to build that for Amazon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnEsG3Kaz6A)